# Dynamic file naming in python

Tags: python

I am creating a prediction model to predict house prices and I have multiple files and I want to name my files dynamically so that they get the name of the file that the prediction algorithm is going through.
The directory works fine and retrieves the data but I am not sure how can I name the new file dynamically I tried using a variable using the file+'.csv' as its definition but it still gave me errors. Can any of you help me figure this out. I'm relatively new to python.

```
mydir = 'Data/houses'
for filepath, file in opened_files(mydir):
    HouseDF = pd.read_csv(file)
    values = list(HouseDF.columns.values)
    print(values)

    print(HouseDF.head())
    with open("Predictions.csv", "w", newline='') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        writer.writerow(["SN", "Month", "Predictions"])
        writer.writerow([1, "Dec 2020", ""])
        writer.writerow([2, "Jan 2021", ""])
        writer.writerow([3, "Feb 2021", ""])
```

Comment: Please give an example of a file name that you would like to construct, and explain what is it based on. Also, explain what is the datatype of `file`.

Comment: The file is of data type CSV. All my files are saved in as for example society1.csv and so on. I would like to construct the name as society1 Prediction.csv so that we can know which society's data is being predicted

Comment: `file+'.csv'` should work fine.  What error did you get with that?

Comment: I want the society's name to come before the word prediction and since each society has different names I want it to change as it goes through all of them

Comment: with open(file+" Predictions.csv", "w", newline='') as file:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: '_io.TextIOWrapper' and 'str'

Comment: I tried this is this correct way to use it?

Comment: ps this was the error that i got

Comment: you have variable `file` in two places and this can make problem. First you have `for filepath, file in ...` and it can be string with filename - but later you do `with open() as file:` and you replace previous string with file-object and you get error.

Comment: First you have for `filepath, file in ... ` and `file` is a string with filename - but later you do `with open() as file:` and you replace previous string with `file-object` and you get error because now `file` is not a string and `file + string` can join `file-object` with `string`. Maybe use variable `filename` instead of `file` in first place - and later `filename + string`

Comment: Oh! I get it ..... so what do you propose I shall change in the code? To get it to work

Comment: I'll try this thanks

Comment: filename= file+".csv" is this how you are suggesting

Comment: The cleanest way is to change `file` to `filename` in the `for` loop: `for filepath, filename in opened_files(mydir)`. That will make it less confusing about which is the file name and which is the file handler.